# Svelte Material UI Circular Progress Indicator not working

Tags: javascript, material-ui, svelte, uicomponents

I cannot get the Svelte Material UI Circular Progress indicator to work. I first tried getting it to work in my project and then decided to test it in Code Sandbox using the code from the documentation. In both projects, I just get back a black circle rather than the indicator. I am not sure if I am misusing smui but I tried a few other components and they worked fine. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my Code Sandbox:
[Svelte Circular Progress Issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-circular-progress-issue-1tr9v4)

Comment: Please include all relevant code *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the theme, you can use the default by adding the `svelte-material-ui` package and importing it in your App.svelte like:

```
import 'svelte-material-ui/bare.css'
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-circular-progress-issue-forked-qhby0r?file=/App.svelte

Comment: I see! Thank you so much :) I was so confused, such a relief